# Autoshape - like posterbox in baposter

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, positioning, posters, baposter

I am making poster in baposter class. What I want is to wrap my story around the one summarizing sentence, that will be placed on the axis made by arrow - like posterboxes in the second column (poster is portrait oriented and has 4 columns). Basically what I want is something like this:[image]
My problem is how to make such arrow - like posterboxes? I tried to serch the web, but found no solution. Any advice on how to deal with that? My current code:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}



\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


% \selectcolormodel{cmyk}

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored


\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}

\newenvironment{boenumerate}
  {\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf\theenumi.}}
  {\end{enumerate}}



\begin{document}


% \definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.45}
% \definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.25}
\definecolor{CENTblue}{RGB}{20,50,250}
\definecolor{CENTyellow}{RGB}{255,237,22}
\definecolor{CENTblek}{RGB}{84,250,255}
\definecolor{CENTorg}{RGB}{84,250,255}
\definecolor{CENTglon}{RGB}{179,166,34}
\definecolor{Jazel}{RGB}{90,255,6}
\definecolor{Oczjeb}{RGB}{236,68,255}
\definecolor{ORG}{RGB}{255,185,10}



\begin{poster}
{
grid=false,
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=CENTyellow, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=CENTyellow, % Border color
headerColorOne=CENTblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=CENTblek, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true,%\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Centera.eps}, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.11\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=1pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
{{\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{Unipres.eps}}} 
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%  Poster title
{
\Huge\textsf %Sans Serif
{Title.
}
} %
%  % Author names
% 
{\sf\vspace{0.2em}\\
\normalsize{Piotr A. Dróżdż$^1$, }
\vspace{1em}\\
\footnotesize{$^1$CENTERA Laboratories, Institute of High Pressure Physics PAS, Warsaw, Poland \\

$^5$Faculty of Physics, University of Warsaw, Warsaw, Poland\\
% \vspace{0.01em}
pdrozdz@ctr.pl}
}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.33]{Centera.eps}}
% University/lab logo


\begin{posterbox}[column=0, row=0, span=4,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=ORG,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=ORG]{\bf Motivation}
Blah blah blah \cite{pitaevskii1961electric}. We are going towards the enlighted future\cite{PhysRevLett.15.190} \lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}





\begin{posterbox}[column=0, row=0.076,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=Jazel,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=Jazel]{rectangle}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}
\begin{posterbox}[column=1, row=0.076,headerfont={},headershape=rectangle,headerColorOne=Jazel,boxColorOne=Jazel,borderColor=Jazel, boxheaderheight=0em]{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=2,row=0.076,span=2,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=Jazel,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=Jazel]{roundedright}
\begin{boenumerate}\compresslist
    \item 1
    \item 2.
    \item maybe 3. but not more
\end{boenumerate}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{posterbox}


\begin{posterbox}[column=0, row=0.28,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=cyan,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=cyan]{rectangle}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}


\begin{posterbox}[column=2,row=0.29,span=2,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=cyan,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=cyan]{roundedright}
\begin{boenumerate}\compresslist
    \item 1
    \item 2.
    \item maybe 3. but not more
\end{boenumerate}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{posterbox}


\begin{posterbox}[column=0, row=0.6,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=Oczjeb,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=Oczjeb]{rectangle}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}


\begin{posterbox}[column=2,row=0.6,span=2,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=Oczjeb,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=Oczjeb]{roundedright}
\begin{boenumerate}\compresslist
    \item 1
    \item 2.
    \item maybe 3. but not more
\end{boenumerate}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=0,row=0.8,span=2,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=red,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=red]{\huge \bf Conclusions}
\large
\begin{boenumerate}\compresslist
    \item 1
    \item 2.
    \item maybe 3. but not more
\end{boenumerate}
\end{posterbox}


\begin{posterbox}[column=2, row=0.83,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=CENTblue,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=CENTblue]{\bf Acknowledgements}
Thank you for help Ladies and Gents.
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=3, row=0.83,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=CENTglon,boxColorOne=white,borderColor=CENTglon]{\bf References}
% %\small % Reduce the font size in this block
 \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
% %\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster


 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
 \bibliography{Bibliografia} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
\end{posterbox}
% \headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,span=1,below=mcs,above=bottom}{


% %\small % Reduce the font size in this block
% \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
% %\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster


% \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
% \bibliography{Bibliografia} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
% }

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Current output:[image]

So I want the all green posterbox to have pointy end. Any advices on how to deal with that? I would be deeply thankful.